# how can i add one of my file in the .gitignore file?

Tags: git, git-add, git-status, git-untracked

I'm new to coding.

I learned about the .gitignore file today, and I succeeded in adding an unwanted file to the .gitignore file but could not add one file on the .gitignore file.

---

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    ".zcompdump-Young\342\200\231s MacBook Pro (3)-5.8.1"
    git/
```

---

I don't want this file to be on my untracked file list.

How can I include this in the .gitignore file?

Why isn't this file included in .gitignorefile as other files?

I was able to add these files in the .gitignore file.

```
.zshrc
.python_history
.stCommitMsg
.subversion/
.viminfo
.vscode/
Applications/
Creative Cloud Files/
Desktop/
Documents/
```

and when I enter git status commend these files weren't not appeared in the untracked list.

What am I doing wrong?
How can I add it to the .gitignore file?

Comment: if you have already initiated a git repository before setting up the `.gitignore`, then the file will always be tracked, even if you include it in the ignore file later. Your only choice is to remove the `.git` directory and create the `.gitignore` then initiate the repo again

Comment: Why can't you add that file to the `.gitignore` file?  You could add it as a prefix, like `.zcompdump*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having to ignore `Applications`, `Desktop` and `Documents`, it looks like you're on a Mac and that you've initialized a Git repository in your home directory.

Don't do that.

Create a subdirectory (call it `Development` for all I care) and put your projects in subdirectories of that one. Then you initialize a Git repository per project directory.

Then delete the .git directory from your home dir.

Comment: can you tell me the reason why I should create a subdirectory? or recommend articles to read to understand this concept? before I do, I know why... Thank you so much!

Comment: Because where else are you storing your project? You're bound to create another one in the future. So just give each their own directory.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `.zcompdump-Young/` to your `.gitingore` and make after modifying `.gitignore` you add it with `git add .gitignore` then check `git status`

Your .gitignore file should look like this:

```
.zshrc
.python_history
.stCommitMsg
.subversion/
.viminfo
.vscode/
Applications/
Creative Cloud Files/
Desktop/
Documents/
.zcompdump-Young/
```